# Running Storybook on amplify in a nextjs project

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, storybook, aws-amplify

Im trying to run storybook from amplify in a nextjs project.
It sets the framework as Nextjs SSR but i went ahead and changed it to React and the app platform was kept as it is to Web Compute

I updated the amplify.yaml file as:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - nvm install
        - nvm use
        - yarn install --immutable
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build-storybook
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: storybook-static
    files:
      - "**/*"
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

But the build always fails with this error

```
2023-02-15T09:45:08.672Z [WARNING]: info
2023-02-15T09:45:08.672Z [WARNING]: => Output directory: /codebuild/output/src160065809/src/dc-extension-get-started/storybook-static
2023-02-15T09:45:08.737Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: build
2023-02-15T09:45:08.739Z [INFO]: ## Build completed successfully
2023-02-15T09:45:08.740Z [INFO]: # Starting caching...
2023-02-15T09:45:08.750Z [INFO]: # Creating cache artifact...
2023-02-15T09:45:21.174Z [INFO]: # Created cache artifact
2023-02-15T09:45:21.296Z [INFO]: # Uploading cache artifact...
2023-02-15T09:45:24.843Z [INFO]: # Uploaded cache artifact
2023-02-15T09:45:24.919Z [INFO]: # Caching completed
2023-02-15T09:45:24.922Z [INFO]: Setting NEXT_PRIVATE_STANDALONE=true to produce .next/standalone directory
2023-02-15T09:45:24.926Z [INFO]: # No custom headers found.
2023-02-15T09:45:24.930Z [ERROR]: !!! CustomerError: Standalone directory not found in /codebuild/output/src160065809/src/dc-extension-get-started/storybook-static/standalone. Please enable output standalone on your next.config.js file or set NEXT_PRIVATE_STANDALONE=true. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing#automatically-copying-traced-files
2023-02-15T09:45:24.930Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-02-15T09:45:24.930Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2023-02-15T09:45:24.982Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
2023-02-15T09:45:24.982Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Looks like it still tries to find a nextjs app how to get the storybook running in a nextjs app on amplify ?

Answer (score 2):

The way I found to solving this was changing the framework of my Amplify branches from "Next.js - **SSR**" to "Next.js - **SSG**". [Here is where I found the guide on doing it.](https://repost.aws/questions/QUAJ8Pkmc8SlGkAAd9olOoMA/amplify-wont-disable-ssr-for-non-ssr-branches-how-to-force-it-to-switch-to-ssg)

Hopefully the following won't be instructing you to doing something that's not recomended, but in order to [setup the CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-creds-create) (if you haven't already) I had to create an IAM user with some privileges. As I was in a rush, I attached Amplify admin access to it. You probably want to be more careful than this.

Then amplify stopped searching for a standalone directory inside ./storybook-static and the build process finished just as expected and the page was deployed.